# What geoprocessing tool to use for analysis of multiple line feature classes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, linear-referencing

I have many line feature classes that I am trying to use in an analysis. For sake of the question I will just use a basic example.

I have a line feature class of State Roads for the state of Florida. I also have a line feature class that shows where the divided sections of roadway are. I would like to split the State Road lines using the divided roadway feature class while keeping the attributes for the divided roadway feature class.

In the picture below, the red lines represent the divided roadway feature class and the green lines represent the State Roads feature class. So I would like the green line to break into three segments using the red lines. I would like to retain the information in the table from both feature classes so I can easily discern where the divided roadways are along state roads, using 1 feature class.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Learn about Linear referencing with ArcGIS http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm

I believe this is the strategy you want to employ.  You could use the Integrate tool, split the lines, then spatial join, but this is a time consuming process.  Linear referencing is a much better solution.

Comment: Why is it a much better solution?  Please [edit] your answer to explain more about what Linear Referencing does, and how it would solve the problem in the question.

Comment: The problem I am having is that the attributes from the divided roadway feature class are being added to the entire line that they intersect with the state roads feature class, but this is incorrect. Only a portion of the state road is divided, that's why I was seeing if there was a way to split the state road based on the divided feature class. 
 
Since my data is the entire state of Florida, there's no way I could split the state road class at each divided segment, there are over 10,000 segments. Was hoping there was a tool that would do the splitting for me.

Comment: or I could just link to the perfectly written explanation and save space.